# Compare a variable with other Date,Datetime

Tags: php, ms-access, datetime, ms-access-2007

I'm using an Access database, and it has a table called `Checkinout` that stores Datetime.  I'm trying to compare that variable to another one but doesn't matter how I try it always gives me an error.

If I use `convert` it tells me that the function `convert` doesn't exist. If I use `cast` it says I'm missing an operator.

Here is an example:

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM Checkinout 
      where Checkinout.Checktime > Cast('26-8-2013' as Datetime) ";
```

I have tried with many different ways like:

```
$date= '26/08/2013 00:00:00 a.m';
$date= '26-08-2013 00:00:00 a.m';
$date= '2013/08/26 00:00:00 a.m';
$date= '2013-08-26 00:00:00 a.m';
```

etc etc, and still doesn't work.

I'm using PHP to do the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access SQL does not include `Cast` or `Convert` functions.  You can use `CDate()` to transform a suitable string to a Date/Time value.

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM Checkinout 
      where Checkinout.Checktime > CDate('2013-8-26') ";
```

Or use `#` delimiters to provide the value as a Date/Time literal.

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM Checkinout 
      where Checkinout.Checktime > #2013-8-26# ";
```

I used *yyyy-m-d* format for the date *string* to avoid any confusion from *d-m-yyy* vs. *m-d-yyyy* locale settings.